# How to get links to have same height as font-size?

Tags: html, css

Links have a greater height than the font-size.

For example a line of text with font-size: 50px has a height of 50px. Yet the link inside the line of text has a height of 68px (there is no padding or margin on the link).

I presume the clickable area around the link has to take into account all the ascenders and descenders of the typeface. And this is why it has a greater height than the font-size.

Hence if the line-height of the text is set to 1em (in this case 50px) and there are several lines in a list the links overlap. Using display: inline-block or block doesn't work as the clickable area on the links is still greater height than the 50px, and so they overlap the text above.

The tightest line-height I can get is line-height: normal, but this gives my lines a height of something like 1.3em. Surely it must be possible to have a line-height of 1em or less, without links overlapping?

```css
nav {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

nav li {
  background-color: green;
}

a:link { color:rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; }
a:visited { color:rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; }
a:hover { color:rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; }
a:active { color:rgb(128, 128, 128); text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="ethical-design.html">Ethics</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Display inline-block or block actually works just fine, so there must be some other styles involved. [Check it here](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/1pkxqfyg/2/)

Comment: Share more css, you shouldn't have this issue at all.

Comment: @skobaljic thank you. I can't understand how this works, but it doesn't in my code. The font I'm using has long decenders and ascenders, could that be why the links have greater height than the font size?

Comment: Well, than it is the font issue, use smaller font, but set height to 1em and maybe overfow: hidden; or try to recompile the font [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` seems to work fine here...

Regarding the clickable area, if you set the height of the anchor to the same 50px as the `font-size` and follow [@skobaljic's advice on using `overflow: hidden`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63504657/how-to-get-links-to-have-same-height-as-font-size/63505170?noredirect=1#comment112296646_63504657), as well as setting the height of the enclosing `li` to 50px, you can get the effect I think you're after...

Note that this will clip the descenders; note how the j in Projects is slightly truncated.

```css
nav {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
}

nav li {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:link {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

a:visited {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

a:active {
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="ethical-design.html">Ethics</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi. I've written more CSS. If you run my code snippet you can see that the the mouse can be touching the link below, but still clicking (hovering) the link above.

Answer (score -1):

set the font-size for the  tag in your css file to be 50px

```css
 a {
    font-size: 50px
    }
```